# What audio formats are supported by QMediaPlayer?

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to figure out what is supported by `QMediaPlayer` in Qt but cannot find a specific list of formats (MP3, AAC, FLAC, MIDI etc.).

Answer (score 5):

There are several backends available in QtMultimedia. For example, on Windows QtMultimedia uses DirectShow, and GStreamer on Linux. So, list of supported formats depends on backend and codecs available on the target system. See, [the list](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/trees/stable/src/plugins) of QtMultimedia plugins and [some info](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/multimediabackend.html) about backends.

Comment: Ahh... Damn. I was really hoping that Qt 5 would unify these and make it so audio support was platform independent.

Comment: If you want a platform independent solution, I would suggest to use LibVLC. That's what I did in my projects. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/trollixx/qtvlc) you can find my Qt wrapper around LibVLC, but it's unfinished yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [QAudioDeviceInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qaudiodeviceinfo.html).

Take a look at QAudioDeviceInfo class and its member function supportedCodecs().

Comment: This only gives 'audio/pcm' as supported codec although I can also play mp3s??